# Delete All Rows apart from highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this.

```
ID | Create Date
---+-------------------------
1  | 2007-06-12 15:44:10:000
1  | 2007-07-12 15:44:10:000
2  | 2007-06-12 15:44:10:000
2  | 2007-07-12 15:44:10:000
2  | 2007-08-12 15:44:10:000
3  | 2007-09-12 15:44:10:000
4  | 2012-06-12 15:44:10:000
5  | 2011-07-12 15:44:10:000
```

I need to keep the `max(createdate)` while deleting all other rows. I also need to keep rows with ID 3,4,5.

Any help would be great.

Note: this is a little abstract. The actual table has millions of Ids that have many duplicate ids with different create dates

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: Sql server 2008 r2

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: As it stands this question is too ambiguous.  using your table show expected results.  I don't know if you need max date per ID or max Date over all ID's or max date for IDs which are not 2,3,4... too many possibilities that expected results would help clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the records that have the most recent date, and delete the rest:

```
;With ToDelete As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id Order By CreateDate Desc) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Delete  ToDelete
Where   RN <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table 
WHERE ID IN 3, 4, 5 OR ID = (SELECT ID FROM table as a
                             WHERE createdate = (SELECT MAX(createdate) FROM 
                              table as b WHERE a.ID = b.ID)))
```

Comment: Sorry the sample I gave you was a little extract. The actual table has millions of Ids that have many dublicate ids with different create dates